# How to add "quoted text" content to email?

Tags: android

I have a webview which shows a mail . I need to forward the content of this webview in an email using the Intents. Now I am able to get the content of the webview but how do I add this content to the outgoing email as "Quoted text " as the native Gmail app does when you try to forward something.

Comment: Escape character? \"I'm quoted text\"

Comment: @0cool Can you post some Code?

Answer (score 0):

Check this for adding Quoted text in Mail content :

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Mail!");
 sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
 Html.fromHtml( "\"I'm quoted text\""
 + "\n\n"
 + "\n\tSent from my Android Mobile"));
 sendIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Email:" +"title"));
```

Similarly you can add any HTML tag here for Design of you Mail to be sent..